# SSRS query first day of last month based on current day

Tags: reporting-services

I have 1 column [Day ID] with format data "YYYYMMDD". Now i want create query EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS with filter: 'Table'[Day ID] = FORMAT(PREVIOUSMONTH(NOW(),"YYYYMMDD").

Example: to day is 20210204 then my filter result is: 'Table'[Day ID] = 20210101.

Can you help me create filter?

Answer (score 0):

To do this in the query, you would DATEADD to subtract the day number from today and then subtract another month:

```
WHERE [Day ID] = CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE())), 112)
```

If you wanted to do this in the report's dataset filter, you would do something similar but with the SSRS report functions like the FORMAT that you had:

Filter Value Expression

```
=FORMAT(DATEADD("M", -1, DATEADD("d", 1 - DAY(TODAY), TODAY)),"yyyyMMdd")
```

Comment: I try with FORMAT(DATEADD("M", -1, DATEADD("d", 1 - DAY(TODAY), TODAY)),"yyyyMMdd") but it's show error "Query (1, 234) The last argument must be one of these keywords: DAY, MONTH, QUARTER, or YEAR. (Microsoft Analysis Services)"
Detail my query:

EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Date Dimension'[Year], 'Date Dimension'[FY Year ID], 'Date Dimension'[Month], 'Date Dimension'[Month Year Desc], FILTER(VALUES('Date Dimension'[Day ID]), ('Date Dimension'[Day ID] = FORMAT(DATEADD("M", -1, DATEADD("d", 1 - DAY(TODAY), TODAY)),"yyyyMMdd"))))

Comment: That expression was meant for use in the Dataset's filter on the Filter tab of the dataset, not in the query. The first one was in SQL for use in a query. I'm not sure about the SSAS syntax tho - you might just filter from the Dataset's Filter tab.